# With BreezeJs how do you handle updating cache for user1 after user2 has made changes?

Tags: caching, breeze

Trying to find the proper solution for breezejs, if user1/device1 has a cached list of projects and user2/device2 updates one of those records, user1 still sees stale data unless they manually refresh.

What are the solutions to make sure User1 gets the new upated data? Is there something I can do on save of entity to remove it from everyone's cache? Is the cache based per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Breeze *EntityManager* cache is a client side cache, so each user/device/application will have its own data.  There is no simple way to keep these caches in sync except by requerying. Optimistic concurrency, providing you are using it, does guarantee that you do not update newer data with older data, but the stale data issue is still very real.

We along with several other Breeze users have investigated using SignalR with Breeze to let Breeze know when and what to refresh, but right now these solutions are all custom. Please add your vote to the Breeze User Voice ( https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions) on this topic if you want to see either examples or tighter integration between Breeze & SignalR.

Comment: Man what a pain in the butt. I voted up the signalR. It becomes more of an issue too, even with SignalR, security. Based on the User logged in, the API only sends back limited data, but now on an update you have to check who all the subscribers are and send the right data to the right subscribers. I know you can use the signalR groups but still a few extra hoops. Seems like the biggest flaw.   Can you use Breeze without Caching enabled?

Comment: Sure, see the noTracking option on EntityQuery BUT this makes a lot of the Breeze functionality much less useful. Note that this is a very common problem with distributed client applications and there are no simple answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe recommend firebase if you need real time data sync in your application