# How should I handle caching in SPA with AngularJs and Breeze?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Currently have an SPA using Angular with Breeze, following examples from John Papa.

I’m using HotTowel.Angular.Breeze 2.2.

How do I handle Breeze caching? For example, if I’m working with data which is cached in one browser and I open another browser, obviously I should still see my old data.

What is the best way to handle my caching issue? Should I try to implement timeouts?

Comment: You opening a new browser after making changes? I have the same/similar caching question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162478/with-breezejs-how-do-you-handle-updating-cache-for-user1-after-user2-has-made-ch/25166398#25166398

Comment: It's not really about opening new browser, it's more like you explained in your question,
user1 -browser1 or device1

VS
user1 -browser2 or device2

how to sync?